# StructureMap Application Sample

Tags: c#, structuremap

I would like to know where I could find a sample C# application written using StructureMap. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [codecampserver](http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/).  It's a nice reference app for a number of things including StructureMap.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure I used Sharp Architecture as my example the first time I implemented StructureMap

http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/

Good luck with it man